# implement scroll to section without anchors

Tags: reactjs

I need to complete the task:
implement scroll to the section for buttons in the menu without anchoring//REACT

const Component = () => {
return (


Section 1
Section 2
Section 3
Section 4

## Page Title

Section 1

I tried scrollIntoView() method, but something I did wrong

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.